# Pygame - player will not jump unless jump button is held down throughout jump

Tags: python, input, pygame

My player is set to jump when the spacebar is pressed,
and to set the Y veloicty (yVel) to 0 when the spacebar is released.

This should result in the smooth jump and fall that I was looking for,
but for some odd reason if I don't hold down the space bar throughout the whole duration of the jump, (i.e when he hits the ground at yPos = 469),
I have to hit the spacebar twice to make him jump again.
Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

My Code:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,screen,image,xPos,yPos,xVel,yVel):
        self.xPos = xPos
        self.yPos = yPos
        self.xVel = xVel
        self.yVel = yVel
        self.image = image
        self.screen = screen

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.xPos,self.yPos))

    def update(self):   

        self.xPos += self.xVel
        self.yPos += self.yVel


        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == K_LEFT:
                            self.xVel = -2
                        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                            self.xVel = 2
                        elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                            if self.yPos == 469:
                                self.Jump()         
                        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                             pass


                if event.type == KEYUP:
                        if event.key == K_LEFT:
                            self.xVel = 0
                        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                            self.xVel = 0
                        elif event.key == K_SPACE:
                            self.yVel = 0
                        elif event.key == K_DOWN:  
                            pass


                self.playerGravity()



    def playerGravity(self):
        if self.xPos > 469:
                    self.xPos = 469
                if self.xPos < 0:
                    self.xPos = 0
                if self.yPos > 469:
                    self.yPos = 469
                if self.yPos < 0:
                    self.yPos = 0
                if self.yPos < 469:
                    self.yVel += 1

                print(self.xPos)
                print(self.yPos)

    def Jump(self):
                ##for i in range(10):
                    self.yVel = -20
                    ##break
```

Comment: I moved your code inline. To format it, you just select it all and press the `{}` button, or hit CMD-K. That indents every line by four spaces, which is all you need to do to format code.

Comment: the more you know, right? thanks.

Comment: Please ensure your code is indented correctly. Otherwise, it's hard to reason about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it is your playerGravity function. You need to think about what it is doing, in particular:

- what is this magic number 469? why do you compare it to both xPos and yPos?
- what is this supposed to be achieving? `self.yPos < 469: self.yVel += 1`

In general you should write meaningful function names and variable names. This means wrapping all of these assignment calls with functions that describe their purpose. I know what `xPos += 1` *does*, but  I don't know the intent - it could easily be a typo. Proper function names (`MoveRight(amount)`) avoid this.

You also need to learn to pinpoint where your code is going 'wrong' - have you checked the value of `self.yPos` under the line `elif event.key == K_SPACE:`? Debugging is a skill that every programmer must learn.

This may not be a direct answer to your question but I prefer teaching a man to fish than giving him one fish...

Comment: my player sprite is 32x32, so if the sprite is at either x or y 469 he is touching the boundary of the screen, be it the wall or the floor. thats what thats for, to keep him on screen, and i figure if he is less than 469 on the Y coordinate, he is in the air and therefore, according to gravity he must have a downward force acting on him. Right? i just dont understand whats happening with the spacebar where i have to hold it down. i even set it to print when the key is pressed and released but i just cant figure it out :(

Comment: And what about the line `elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.yVel = 0`? We can keep doing this for every line in your code, but as I said, it would be a lot easier if you made clear the **intent** of your code. Some people do it through comments, some do it through naming, it doesn't matter too much **as long as you do it**

Comment: i agree completely. I have found that even when i hold the spacebar through the whole jump sequence, and the player is back on the ground (@ 469 yPos) and i let go it returns self.yPos == 469 as false. still unsure as to why though.

Answer (score 0):

where i checked to see if the ball was on the floor:

```
if self.yPos > 469:
    self.yPos = 469
```

i should have said

```
if self.yPos > 469:
    self.**yVel** = 0
```

because instead of holding the balls position at 469 the latter script simply says no velocity, in other words no movemnt but the ball is still free. whew, that one was a doozie <_>

Comment: See my answer - if you had created a function `ResetVelocity()` you would have spotted this instantly, or possibly not even made the mistake at all.